# Converting a pointer to a byte slice

Tags: pointers, go, system-calls, mmap, virtualalloc

The `Mmap()` syscall in the `x/sys/unix` [package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Mmap) in Golang returns a `[]byte` type, while the underlying syscall actually returns a pointer. How does it do this?

More specifically, in [this](https://github.com/alexbrainman/winapi/blob/master/zsyscall_windows.go#L225) package by a Golang developer, the `VirtualAlloc` function simply returns a pointer. How can this be converted to a byte slice, the same way as it's done in the Unix package?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/d75a52659825e75fff6158388dddc6a5b04f9ba5/unix/syscall_unix.go#L72-L80 ([Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/An7jG5xl2W))

Comment: @mkopriva Wow, can't believe I missed that. Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: the comment is now posted as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Go 1.17, you can now use [unsafe.Slice](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Slice):

```golang
mySlice := unsafe.Slice(ptr, numElements)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the `unsafe` package you could do something similar to what's being done in the [Mmap](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/45f251ad6cfe0a8fa1aeac0c2c8e42bfe3549c29/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go#L66-L71) method's unix implementation:

```golang
type sliceHeader struct {
    addr unsafe.Pointer
    len int
    cap int
}

var b []byte
hdr := (*sliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
hdr.addr = unsafe.Pointer(addr)
hdr.cap = length
hdr.len = length
```

Here's a [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/ejI7N5wqMaa).

Comment: There is an error in this solution. Since `uintptr` has no [pointer semantics](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer), this pointer may be collected by the GC, leading to incredibly hard bugs. The `addr` field should have the `unsafe.Pointer` type, as seen [here](https://golang.org/pkg/internal/unsafeheader/#Slice).

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like `C.GoBytes` (e.g. [see here](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C)):

```
// C data with explicit length to Go []byte
func C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer, C.int) []byte
```